# Приведение типа указателя наследника

Tags: c++, указатели, преобразование-типов, приведение

```
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
class Hero {

protected:
    int b;
public:
    virtual void logic(int a) {
        b = a;
        cout << "hero" << ++a;
    }
};

class Bad :public Hero
{
public:
    void logic(int a, int b) {
        this->b = a;
        this->b = b;
        cout << "bad"<<a<<b;
    }
};




class Storage
{
    vector<Hero*> heroes;
public:
    template<class T>
    void add_hero() {
        heroes.push_back(new T());
    }

    template<class T>
    T get() {
        for (auto hero : heroes) {
            if(typeid(hero)==typeid(T))
                return hero;//вот проблемная строка
        }
    }
    
};

int main() {
    Storage st;
    st.add_hero<Hero>();
    st.add_hero<Bad>();
    st.get<Bad>().logic(10,2);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: ошибка]

как исправить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В цикле

```
for (auto hero : heroes) {
        if(typeid(hero)==typeid(T))
            return hero;//вот проблемная строка
    }
```

переменная `hero` имеет тип указателя, а функция `typeid` в основном имеет смысл только для ссылок. Добавьте везде звёздочку.

```
for (auto hero : heroes) {
        if(typeid(*hero)==typeid(T))
            return *hero;//вот проблемная строка
    }
```

дальше так как вы определили тип с помощью `typeid`, то вам нужно вручную сделать смену типа с помощью `static_cast`:

```
if(typeid(*hero)==typeid(T))
   return static_cast<T&>(*hero);
```

Возвращать копию элемента всегда плохая идея, возвращайте ссылку.

```
template<class T>
  T & get() {
    for (auto hero : heroes) {
        if(typeid(*hero)==typeid(T))
            return static_cast<T&>(*hero);
    }
  }
```

Comment: выход из положения, но это не избавляет от плохого подхода.

Comment: `static_cast` не сработает, если наследование виртуальное. По хорошему, надо примерно так: `if constexpr (requires{static_cast<T&>(*hero);}) return static_cast...; else return dynamic_cast...;`. Или, если устраивает нахожить потомка при передаче в `T` типа родителя: `if (auto p = dynamic_cast<T*>(hero)) return *p;`.

Comment: тут ещё нужно добавлять исключения при отсутствии элементов, а также намекнуть, что нужно добавить виртуальный деструктор, но это уже совсем другая история. @AR Hovsepyan

Answer (score 0):

Storage хранит вектор указателей на героев.
После вызовов :

```
st.add_hero<Hero>();
st.add_hero<Bad>();
```

этот вектор будет хранить  один адрес  героя и один адрес плохого.

Теперь что делает  `st.get<Bad>()`?
Она ничего не возвращает, так как вектор хранит  `Hero*` и его тип не совпадает с типом `Bad`, а компилятор пытается как нибудь преобразовать `Hero*` в `Bad`. Если бы у него это получилось, то он мог вызвать функцию_член logic(10,2), но это не возможно. Вообще пишите что нибудь осмысленное. А то у вас ерунда какая то...